# Apache Mod Rewrite

Tags: apache, configuration, mod-rewrite

In my Apache configuration, I have the following statement:

```
RewriteRule ^/classic(.*) /$1 [nc,l]
```

This will return all statements to http://localhost/classic basic the base htdoc folder (so index.html is used)

I want to be able to enter http://localhost/classic/somefolder and make it go the a specific folder in the htdocs.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/classic/somefolder/(.*)$ /elsewhere/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/classic/(.*)$ /$1 [NC,L]
```